# Jenkins build error

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem and I really have no idea how to fix it.  I'm trying to build a project using Jenkins.  The IDE installed on our build machine is Embarcedero C++ Builder XE.
This is the project is configure at the build state.\

MSBuildVersion: MSBuild 2.0
MSBuild Build File: testProject\Platforms\Common\AuthoringTool\FrontEnd\testProject.cbproj
Command Line Arguments: /t:Clean;Make /p:Config=Release

Update:  Part of the problem was with the account.  We changed Jenkins to run as a service and it was getting wrong paths.  That has been fixed but now I'm having a postbuildevent error.

```
    Target PostBuildEvent:
cd c:\jenkins\workspace\testProject\testProject\Platforms\Common\AuthoringTool\Image\
implib testProject.lib vat.exe
'implib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(194,5): error MSB3073: The command "cd c:\jenkins\workspace\testProject\testProject\Platforms\Common\AuthoringTool\Image\
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(194,5): error MSB3073: implib testProject.lib testProject.exe" exited with code 9009.
```

Done building target "PostBuildEvent" in project "testProject.cbproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "testProject.cbproj" -- FAILED.

When I try to build the project manually the project successfully compile.  I also checked the Jenkins workspace and all of the files are at their correct locations.  Any suggestions on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you run Jenkins as the same user as when you build it manually?

Comment: To answer your question, Yes Jenkins is supposed to use the same user.  When I set it to run as a service I forgot to add the user data.  Now I'm now having a PostBuildEvent problem.  I tried to add the implib command path in Jenkins but that didn't help.

Comment: @themaniac27 Are the lines shown from MS Build or from an "Execute Windows Batch Command" build step?  I am guessing from MS Build.  Try putting them in a Windows Batch step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using "Inject environment variables to the build process", with the path to implib.  I don't know why Peter solution didn't work.  It seems like it should have.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that 'implib' is on your system path.

This can be done by echoing the %PATH% in your PostBuildEvent. If it's not on the path you can either add it to the environment, or use Jenkins to automatically reference the location.

Another option would be to explicitly execute the command rather than assuming it'll be on the path...

ie, update your PostBuildEvent to...

```
cd c:\jenkins\workspace\testProject\testProject\Platforms\Common\AuthoringTool\Image\
C:\<path_to_implib_command>\implib testProject.lib vat.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I figured this was the problem but the solution did not work.